# Inheriting a variable from a class

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I am working on a project which has an abstract class A and several classes, suppose class B, C, D which all inherit publicly from class A.

Class A has a bunch of getters and setters as well as a few private member variables.

One of these member variables is a string called name.

Another one of these member variables is a character called abbreviation, which holds the first character of the name string.

How can I go about setting the string and character variables without needing getters and setters to name them in the code of functions I write.
I do not want to have to set them at the start of the program run.

Is it possible to set them in their constructors?
For example:

```
// B constructor
B::B() {
name = "B is the name of this variable";
abbreviation = 'B';
}
```

Thanks in advance ! :D

Comment: Please show the definition of the class A instead of the long description of the class A.

Comment: Constructor of `A` should initialise the members of `A`, for example `A::A(const std::string &chosen_name) : name(chosen_name)) {}`.    Derived classes then use a relevant constructor of `A`.  For example `B::B() : A("my name is B") {}`.     The trick is to ensure that `A` provides constructors with suitable argument lists that can be used by derived class constructors.     Note that it is still often necessary to have setters and getters in base class - for example, if functions outside class `A` need to set or get values of `A`s private members.

Comment: I think the majority of your question is based upon misunderstandings that potentially render your question moot. Maybe it would be better if you gave a more complete example (including `A` with its `name` member) showing what you want to do, and contrast that with an example showing what you think the only alternative is?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to modify `name` and `abbreviation` from inherited sub classes. In order to do that you should declare said variables as `protected` instead of `private`.

`protected` methods and variables are members that only the class itself and it's sub-classes can access.

Now if instead you are interested in free functions being able to access said values, you should declare them as `friend`, here is an example:

```
class A{
    private:
        std::string name;
        char abbreviation;

        friend void func( A obj );
}

void func( A obj ){
    obj.name = "that's my name!";
    obj.abbreviation = 't';
}
```

Comment: If you don't like the edit you can just rollback

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set those variables using a constructor initializer list if that is what you are looking for. Then every time you produce an object those attributes will be set to their specified default values.

see here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor
for more details.

you would use it something like

B() : name{"B is the name of this variable"}, abbreviation{'B'}    {}